# in python, how I append the index of a certain string in a list to another list if there are duplicate entries in the first list?

Tags: python, list, append

Say I have a list K, and a list B. If an entry in K fulfills my condition x, I want the index of that entry in my list B. The problem is since there are duplicate entries in the first list, using k.index only gives me the index of the first occurrence in that list. Here's what I have:

```
for i in k:

    if i = x:

        b.append(k.index(i))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
for n, item in enumerate(k):
    if item == x:
        b.append(n)
```

The built-in enumerate function returns an index value for the iterations starting at 0 just like a list index

Comment: I was first :) @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Now that I see the UTC timestamp, you're right... you were 1 second faster. Upvoted ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the [built-in `enumerate` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of `list.index`:

> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration. The `__next__()` method of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a count (from *start* which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over *iterable*.

```
for idx, i in enumerate(k):
    if i == x:
        b.append(idx)
```